# Open a web page to a specific line or paragraph

Tags: python, r, web

Is it possible to open a web page at a certain point, ideally a line number, or at a point identified with an Xpath query (not an anchor) using either R or python to open a url within a browser, for example.

```
webbrowser.open(url)

shell.exec(url)
```

Will it depend on the browser used, or need to be controlled by the browser rather than the script used to open it?

The idea is to search for a term within a web page and have the page open at the specific line containing the search term, instead of just opening the url.

Comment: Do you mean have the window scroll to the link on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get fancy with the HTML, first by finding the link you want on the page, then creating a new element with a specific ID you name, and then tell the browser to load that edited page.

```
site: www.example.com
<p> lorem ipsum </p>
```

and then you change the `p`'s `id` to `id="scrollhere"`

```
site: www.example.com
<p id="scrollhere" > lorem ipsum </p>
```

and then tell your browser to load `www.example.com/#scrollhere`. The trick would be getting the edited page to the browser.

Comment: Do you mean you could copy the web page, store it locally, edit it, and then open it from the local location.

Comment: @CCID I haven't played too much with mechanize or PAMIE, but I bet you can alter the page you're browsing enough to edit the html and reload the page. No saving necessary, but I'm not positive though.